# JRebel Eclipse External Jetty Deployment w/o Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, ant, jrebel, jetty-9

New to JRebel here. Is there anyway to run JRebel deployment without Maven? I could run using Ant `build.xml` to deploy into the `webapps` folder of Jetty but then it has to be manually trigger.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course. JRebel doesn't depend on Maven. What you need is to make sure that [rebel.xml configuration file](http://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/standalone/config.html) is deployed with the application - the JRebel will be able to locate the resources (i.e. classes and static HTML/JS/CSS files).

Make sure that rebel.xml ends up in WEB-INF/classes of the WAR package. Then you'd just compile only the changed classes with your IDE and JRebel will make the updates.